# Relationship between squaring a complex number and acceleration

Tags: complex-numbers, physics

I know that the formula relating initial velocity, final velocity, acceleration, and distance is $v^2-u^2=2as$ and that squaring a complex number $v+u\mathrm{i}$ leads to $(v^2-u^2)+(2uv)\mathrm{i}$, so is there any reason why the two are so similar or is that just by chance?

Comment: We need to get $3$ blue $1$ brown in here. (He's a youtuber who makes great visual connections with complex numbers)

Comment: But if you look at the change in kinetic Energy from start to end of a process  would you consider that as complex numbers i.e. $\Delta K.E = \frac{m}{2}\left(v^2-u^2\right)$? I guess if one considers the initial velocity is on a perpendicular axis as the final then it would make sense. I even tried to expand the equations of motion to include this notation $v_c = v + iu$, but the equations are not exactly ideal/simpler. Though,  I am also very happy to see something novel. However, @ElliotG the youtuber you mention is fantastic, and if anyone could give insight he would be great.

Comment: @Alexander3.14 after watching his latest video, I agree that there must be some connection between the parabolas you get through mapping grid lines by squaring them and the parabolic motion you get with a constant acceleration.

Comment: @ElliotG: I'm not sure if there's really any connection to this exact question, but it might be worth mentioning that there is an interesting section in Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* about the squaring map $z \mapsto z^2$ taking orbits of the harmonic oscillator to orbits of the Kepler problem. (Chapter 5, Section X, “Celestial Mechanics“.)

Comment: I'm of a mind that the one has nothing to with the other. In the first place, what sense does is make to put $u$ and $v$ on different axes in the complex plane. If anything, it should be velocity and acceleration, so that you'd have a phase plane. In the second place, there is that pesky $(2uv)i$ lurking about. What are you going to do about that? Now, I'm just talking off the top of my head and I would like to be proven wrong so that I can learn something new. So go ahead and do it!

Comment: @CyeWaldman: Make it an answer?